# How to get a "live screenshot" in windows

Tags: windows, screenshot

Quick question – do you know any software or way of doing a live screenshot of a window and bring it to the foreground? It’d be like picture link in Excel...

My problem is that I am running various tasks in IE and Oracle, and they take forever but i have no way of seeing if they’re done without tabbing back into them all the time. I want something so that I can always see in the foreground the status bar/egg-timers thingy for them.

Thanks all

Comment: Sounds like good reason to badger the boss for a second monitor... ;-)

Comment: i have a second monitor.. maybe i need a third!

Comment: Write an application that uses [DWM thumbnails](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969541(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks Raymond - that looks useful. Unfortunately I'm no expert(!) and have no idea where i'd begin in terms of writing an application - what language, what software i'd need to build it, etc etc.